# How to add additional placeholder values to Web API routes

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm researching building a restful API using the ASP.NET Web API framework.

The basic route format that's used is

```
api/{controller}/public/{category}/{id}
```

I've read a lot about how the framework resolves the controllers and actions to execute within those controllers, and feel pretty comfortable with that.

Ultimately, what I need to do, however, is add an additional placeholder element before the controller section which will act as a routing element to determine the endpoint the action should be executed against.  Ex.

```
api/{endpointId}/{controller}/public/{category}/{id}
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish this in the Web API framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Attribute routing (specified as an attribute, either on the entire controller class or each method individually) or conventional routing. If each controller can have multiple possible endpoints, it may be harder to achieve what you want through attribute routing, albeit still possible. If you choose to go the conventional route (pun intended), you could set that up similar to this way:

Adapted from the [Web API 2 docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2):

```
    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Attribute routing.
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Convention-based routing.
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{endpointId}/{controller}/public/{category}/{id}",
                defaults: new { endpointId = "1", controller = "DefaultController", category = "DefaultCategory"
id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        } }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was only looking at the API v1 routing.  I think the attribute routing in API 2 is going to get me what I need.